# I am trying to add jQuery code in phtml file but its not working in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.4

I am trying to add jQuery code in `phtml` file but it's not working in Magento 1, But it's working in console.
Please help me.
Here is my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $j(document).ready(function($) {

    $('div.itemSubMenu.designer.level1').hide();      
       $("a.itemMenuName.designer.level1").hover(function () {

            $(this).next('div.itemSubMenu.designer.level1').slideToggle('slow');

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is that PHTML loading by AJAX?

Comment: yes this PHTML loading by AJAX